# What is wrong with this WebGL code?

Tags: webgl

I am trying to run this example from

http://www.w3schools.eu/2012/07/webgl-essentials-part-i/

However I ended up with few errors. I am new to this (just learning) and I would like to know why the example is not running. I have pasted the code here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Site.css" type="text/css" />
    <script>


        function WebGL(CID, FSID, VSID) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById(CID);

            if (!canvas.getContext("webgl") && !canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl"))
                alert("Your Browser Doesn't Support WebGL");
            else {
                this.GL = (canvas.getContext("webgl")) ? canvas.getContext("webgl") : canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");

                this.GL.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
                this.GL.enable(this.GL.DEPTH_TEST);
                this.GL.depthFunc(this.GL.LEQUAL); 
                this.AspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;

                var FShader = document.getElementById(FSID);
                var VShader = document.getElementById(VSID);


                if (!FShader || !VShader)
                    alert("Error, Could Not Find Shaders");
                else {
                    //Load and Compile Fragment Shader
                    var Code = LoadShader(FShader);
                    FShader = this.GL.createShader(this.GL.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
                    this.GL.shaderSource(FShader, Code);
                    this.GL.compileShader(FShader);

                    //Load and Compile Vertex Shader
                    Code = LoadShader(VShader);
                    VShader = this.GL.createShader(this.GL.VERTEX_SHADER);
                    this.GL.shaderSource(VShader, Code);
                    this.GL.compileShader(VShader);

                    //Create The Shader Program
                    this.ShaderProgram = this.GL.createProgram();
                    this.GL.attachShader(this.ShaderProgram, FShader);
                    this.GL.attachShader(this.ShaderProgram, VShader);
                    this.GL.linkProgram(this.ShaderProgram);
                    this.GL.useProgram(this.ShaderProgram);

                    //Link Vertex Position Attribute from Shader
                    this.VertexPosition = this.GL.getAttribLocation(this.ShaderProgram, "VertexPosition");
                    this.GL.enableVertexAttribArray(this.VertexPosition);

                    //Link Texture Coordinate Attribute from Shader
                    this.VertexTexture = this.GL.getAttribLocation(this.ShaderProgram, "TextureCoord");
                    this.GL.enableVertexAttribArray(this.VertexTexture);
                }
            }

            this.Draw = function (Object, Texture) {
                var VertexBuffer = this.GL.createBuffer(); //Create a New Buffer

                //Bind it as The Current Buffer
                this.GL.bindBuffer(this.GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBuffer);

                // Fill it With the Data
                this.GL.bufferData(this.GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(Object.Vertices), this.GL.STATIC_DRAW);

                //Connect Buffer To Shader's attribute
                this.GL.vertexAttribPointer(this.VertexPosition, 3, this.GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

                //Repeat For The next Two
                var TextureBuffer = this.GL.createBuffer();
                this.GL.bindBuffer(this.GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, TextureBuffer);
                this.GL.bufferData(this.GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(Object.Texture), this.GL.STATIC_DRAW);
                this.GL.vertexAttribPointer(this.VertexTexture, 2, this.GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

                var TriangleBuffer = this.GL.createBuffer();
                this.GL.bindBuffer(this.GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, TriangleBuffer);
                this.GL.bufferData(this.GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(Object.Triangles), this.GL.STATIC_DRAW);

                //Generate The Perspective Matrix
                var PerspectiveMatrix = MakePerspective(45, this.AspectRatio, 1, 10000.0);

                var TransformMatrix = MakeTransform(Object);

                //Set slot 0 as the active Texture
                this.GL.activeTexture(this.GL.TEXTURE0);

                //Load in the Texture To Memory
                this.GL.bindTexture(this.GL.TEXTURE_2D, Texture);

                //Update The Texture Sampler in the fragment shader to use slot 0
                this.GL.uniform1i(this.GL.getUniformLocation(this.ShaderProgram, "uSampler"), 0);

                //Set The Perspective and Transformation Matrices
                var pmatrix = this.GL.getUniformLocation(this.ShaderProgram, "PerspectiveMatrix");
                this.GL.uniformMatrix4fv(pmatrix, false, new Float32Array(PerspectiveMatrix));

                var tmatrix = this.GL.getUniformLocation(this.ShaderProgram, "TransformationMatrix");
                this.GL.uniformMatrix4fv(tmatrix, false, new Float32Array(TransformMatrix));

                //Draw The Triangles
                //this.GL.drawElements(this.GL.TRIANGLES, Object.Triangles.length, this.GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

                this.GL.drawArrays(this.GL.TRIANGLES, Object.Vertices, Object.Vertices.length);
            };

            this.LoadTexture = function (Img) {
                //Create a new Texture and Assign it as the active one
                var TempTex = this.GL.createTexture();
                this.GL.bindTexture(this.GL.TEXTURE_2D, TempTex);

                //Flip Positive Y (Optional)
                this.GL.pixelStorei(this.GL.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

                //Load in The Image
                this.GL.texImage2D(this.GL.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this.GL.RGBA, this.GL.RGBA, this.GL.UNSIGNED_BYTE, Img);

                //Setup Scaling properties
                this.GL.texParameteri(this.GL.TEXTURE_2D, this.GL.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, this.GL.LINEAR);

                this.GL.texParameteri(this.GL.TEXTURE_2D, this.GL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, this.GL.LINEAR);
                //this.GL.texParameteri(this.GL.TEXTURE_2D, this.GL.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, this.GL.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
                //this.GL.generateMipmap(this.GL.TEXTURE_2D);
                this.GL.texParameteri(this.GL.TEXTURE_2D, this.GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, this.GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                this.GL.texParameteri(this.GL.TEXTURE_2D, this.GL.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, this.GL.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

                //Unbind the texture and return it.
                this.GL.bindTexture(this.GL.TEXTURE_2D, null);
                return TempTex;
            };

        }

        function LoadShader(Script) {
            var Code = "";
            var CurrentChild = Script.firstChild;
            while (CurrentChild) {
                if (CurrentChild.nodeType == CurrentChild.TEXT_NODE)
                    Code += CurrentChild.textContent;
                CurrentChild = CurrentChild.nextSibling;
            }
            return Code;
        }

        function MakePerspective(FOV, AspectRatio, Closest, Farest) {
            var YLimit = Closest * Math.tan(FOV * Math.PI / 360);
            var A = -(Farest + Closest) / (Farest - Closest);
            var B = -2 * Farest * Closest / (Farest - Closest);
            var C = (2 * Closest) / ((YLimit * AspectRatio) * 2);
            var D = (2 * Closest) / (YLimit * 2);
            return [
                C, 0, 0, 0,
                0, D, 0, 0,
                0, 0, A, -1,
                0, 0, B, 0
            ];
        }

        function MakeTransform(Object) {
            return [
                1, 0, 0, 0,
                0, 1, 0, 0,
                0, 0, 1, 0,
                0, 0, -6, 1
            ];
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:Start();">

        <script>
            var GL; 

            //Our finished texture
            var Texture;

            //This will hold the textures image 
            var TextureImage;

            function Start() {
                GL = new WebGL("drawArea", "FragmentShader", "VertexShader");
                TextureImage = new Image();

                TextureImage.onload = function () {
                    Texture = GL.LoadTexture(TextureImage);
                    GL.Draw(Cube, Texture);
                };

                TextureImage.src = "Texture.png";
            }


        </script>
    <div>
        <canvas id="drawArea" class="building-container">

        </canvas>        
    </div>
    <script id="VertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute highp vec3 VertexPosition;
        attribute highp vec2 TextureCoord;

        uniform highp mat4 TransformationMatrix;
        uniform highp mat4 PerspectiveMatrix;

        varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

        void main(void) {
            gl_Position = PerspectiveMatrix * TransformationMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
            vTextureCoord = TextureCoord;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="FragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment"> 
        varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

        uniform sampler2D uSampler;

        void main(void) {
            highp vec4 texelColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
            gl_FragColor = texelColor;
        }     
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi Ian... "GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1 - this was the error"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See full fixed file here: http://pastebin.com/PtZXvj5v

1) Replace:

```
this.GL.bufferData(this.GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(Object.Triangles), this.GL.STATIC_DRAW);
```

With:

```
this.GL.bufferData(this.GL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(Object.Triangles), this.GL.STATIC_DRAW);
```

2) Replace:

```
//Draw The Triangles
//this.GL.drawElements(this.GL.TRIANGLES, Object.Triangles.length, this.GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

this.GL.drawArrays(this.GL.TRIANGLES, Object.Vertices, Object.Vertices.length);
```

With:

```
//Draw The Triangles
this.GL.drawElements(this.GL.TRIANGLES, Object.Triangles.length, this.GL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

//this.GL.drawArrays(this.GL.TRIANGLES, Object.Vertices, Object.Vertices.length);
```

3) Add the Cube object, since it is missing entirely.

4) Locally I replaced:

```
TextureImage.src = "Texture.png";
```

With:

```
TextureImage.src = "Texture.jpg";
```

In order to use one local JPG image as bogus texture, since I don't have the original PNG file.